# epson thermal printer printing bitmap image

Tags: php, bitmap, epson

Edit:
So after a day of messing with everything.  My issue was with sprintf. I originally thought my loop was wrong.

`sprintf('%02x',base_convert($binary, 2, 16));`

I had to use s instead of x to get the proper output.  The X was converting FF to 00, but others it converted fine.  Here's the loop I used to go through the wbmp, note I re-sized the image so it /8, 24.

```
$w = imagesx($im);
$h = imagesy($im);

for($x = 0; $x <= $w; $x++)
{
  $image = "";
  $cntr = 0;
  for($y = 0; $y <= $h; $y++)
  {
      $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
      $image .= ($rgb == "") ? 0 : $rgb; //resizing causes value to return blank

      if(strlen($image) == 8)
      {

        $imgHex = sprintf('%02s',base_convert($image, 2, 16));
        $cntr++;
        $line[$lineNum] .= $imgHex;
        if($cntr == 3)
        {
          $lineNum++;
          $cntr = 0;
        }
        $image = "";
      }
  }
  $lineNum = 0;
}
```

Comment: 01001001 is binary for 73.  What happens if you send 73?

Comment: I've clarified my question as to what I'm trying to do.  Poor example on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a number to byte, you might try AND-ing it with 0xFF. That will cut off all bits outside the one-byte range.

```
slice |= 0xFF & ((v ? 1 : 0) << (7 - b));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that actually did what my original question asked, I just misunderstood the code.  I don't know rules are, but I can award you the answer, if that's needed, since you did actually answer my question.  I just failed to ask the proper question.

Comment: its ok, i dont need the points. Better try to improve the question to make better sense